# How to programmatically set minX or maxX bounds of a JavaFX ScrollPane ViewPort?

Tags: javafx, scrollpane

I can get `minX` of viewport bounds by `scrollView.getViewportBounds().getMinX()`, but how can I set it?

I think a solution that can help me with this problem is: [JavaFX How to scroll ScrollPane to have node in the middle of view port?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18588536/javafx-how-to-scroll-scrollpane-to-have-node-in-the-middle-of-view-por)

Answer (score 1):

You can't. `getViewportBounds()` returns a `Bounds` object which is immutable.

I'm guessing you want to restrict where the scrollpane can scroll to? Then you need to use the `hmax`, `hmin`, `hvalue` and `vmax`, `vmin`, `vvalue` properties of the [ScrollPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/ScrollPane.html).